# Phonegap - Cordova CLI create Titanium Studio folder after installed

Tags: node.js, cordova, titanium, npm

Hello everybody I'm about to install cordova - phonegap on OSX 10.9
Before I have a Appcelerator Titanium installed on my machine then I removed it.
I have Node and NPM installed on my machine, trying this:

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
```

The installation is ok but this is a weird thing after cordova installed, it creates a Titanium Studio folder in my Applications folder and npm install cordova into the "Titanium app folder content", WHY THE F-??
And of course this:

```
-bash: cordova: command not found
```

I think the problem is the PATH variable, but I changed several times the path and nothing happens, please tell me if you know how to fix this. I can't run cordova on my machine.
Here is the ouput after installation:

```
...................
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlbuilder
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmlbuilder
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/xmldom
/Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/bin/cordova -> /Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova cordova@3.1.0-0.2.0 /Applications/Titanium Studio/TitaniumStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/Password:/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova
...................
```

Comment: Please help, I need to create an ios app, if you have questions please ask, whatever you need.

Comment: If you run 'which cordova' what is the output?  I wonder if you didn't fully uninstall titanium.  Also, can you show your output for 'which npm'?  Maybe titanium installed a custom version of the node package manager, which you'll need to uninstall.